# I get an Uncaught Invariant Violation: could not find react-redux context value; even if my app is wrapped in a Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So I get the error :

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider

With this error block right under:

```
The above error occurred in the <_default> component:
  in _default (created by Context.Consumer)
  in Route (created by App)
  in Switch (created by App)
  in div (created by DevMenu)
  in DevMenu (created by App)
  in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
  in BrowserRouter (created by App)
  in Suspense (created by App)
  in App (created by Root)
  in Provider (created by Root)
  in Root
```

So we can see that my component Route is wrapped in the Provider. Why does the error appear!?

I dont have any idea what more I can do. Any suggestion?

When I run `yarn` list `react-redux` I get:

```
├─ @uma/web-assembler@0.5.0
│  └─ react-redux@7.2.0
└─ react-redux@7.1.0
```

Comment: Could you run `npm ls react-redux` and edit your question to include the output? It could be that some dependency is pulling in a different version of `react-redux`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was it!

I had 2 different version of react-redux in my different package! I made sure to have the same one everywhere, and it look like it worked!

Thanks!